# How to make axis "smart" and "flexible" so that the starting/end points on axis are sensible in D3 V4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following [Line Graph (CodePen)](http://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/YGRbNj) and as you can see, the Y-Axis isn't very smart. It begins from `0` when it should begin from somewhere near `2200`.

My guess was that this would be to do with scales:

```
// set the ranges
var x = d3.scalePoint().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
```

But I tried all sorts to get this to behave the "smart" and "flexible" way and couldn't.

How can I make the axis smarter? So if tomorrow I feed the chart a different set of data that starts at `150`, the code is smart enough to draw relevant axis values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the Y axis starting at `0`, you shouldn't set the lower value in the domain to zero, as you did:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(result, function(d) { 
    return d.consumption;
})]);
```

If you want the Y axis to start next to the minimum value, you should use:

```
y.domain([d3.min(result, function(d) {
    return d.consumption; })*0.975,
d3.max(result, function(d) { 
    return d.consumption; })*1.025
]);
```

Here, the numbers 0.975 and 1.025 are just values to make the axis going a little bit below and after the minimum and maximum values, respectively. You can change them or remove them.

Here is your updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgOBvO?editors=0010

PS: while in a bar chart it's highly recommended to always use a zero baseline for the Y axis, there is no problem using a non-zero baseline for the Y axis in a time series (line chart).

Comment: I knew there had to be something, I just couldn't find it. Thanks @GerardoFurtado. Are you this good at teaching Biology too? :D